# Special usage of verbs - like "to have [some property]" - in sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs

What is the "grammatical category" of "to have" in these contexts?

> We choose these words to have length at least two.

> He built this car to have better aerodynamic properties.

Surely, "have" is a verb, but it is not used as a verb "in the strict sense" in the above sentences. Why we do not say, for example, "He built this car to has [...]" - it seems that only "to have" is possible here. Similar sentence:

> I learn to write better.

The part "to write better" seems to be an object, and the verb "write" does not seem to obey the usual "subject-verb-object"-scheme?

Can anyone please explain the rules behind this usage of verbs, and how this is named?

Comment: 'Possess' works with your first two examples. They are examples of the to-infinitive clause used to convey the sense 'to have/possess/display a property', not the 'in order to' sense. 'We built this car to go faster' can have either sense: 'We built this car  in such a way that it would be faster' or the -in order to' sense,  'We built this car so we / mankind could go faster'. 'Have' is just one suitable infinitive . 'We chose these words to be understandable by all the children'. 'They rebuilt the lighthouse to be visible further out to sea.'

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between finite clauses and nonfinite clauses? Are you asking about clauses used as complements rather than as adjuncts?  Are you asking about purpose, reason, or result clauses?

Comment: “I learn” is not good as you are using it. “I will learn” or “I learned” might be better, depending on the intended tense.